# Changing focus between UITextFields in cells at same UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

In my iPad application i have few UITableView on same view created programmatically. They must pretend one multicolumn table. Each cell contains UITextField. It's size is equal to cell's size (its the reason why i cant get UITableView's delegate methods didSelect/didDeselect row). My problem is when i begin edit one text field then try to remove focus to other textfield it needs two taps. After first tap no one of cell is not editing. Such behavior observing only inside same table. If i want to change focus to other table its possible in one tap. What i missed?

Here is my UITextField Delegate methods in Cell's class

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([_delegate checkForAccess:self]) {
        if (!((CTKTextField *)textField).isEditable)
        {
            [_delegate callPickerUnderCell:self];
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            [_delegate getPosition:self];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    else return NO;
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (_textField.text.length == -1)
    {
        _textField.rightView = nil;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *input = textField.text;

    [_delegate saveEdit:self withText:input];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is called after first tap and you return `YES` then text field starts editing. Probably you are making `endEditing` to the whole `tableView` after that.

If you call `endEditing` on the specific cell in your cell's delegate instead of the whole table view it should work.

Answer (score 0):

That might be caused by `autocapitalizationType`. Your have to dismiss the auto correction before getting your `textField becomeFirstResponder`. Disable it will solve the problem.

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

Edit:
I was confused, try this one:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Comment: @VictorIppolitov So I guess some screenshots or pieces of code will be helpful and much more clear.

Comment: So where did you apply my solution? Directly in textField's delegate or at the point of it's creation?

Comment: My textField is a custom class so i added your solution in initWithFrame method in my textField class. Also i tried with adding it at a point of creation textField object.

Comment: @VictorIppolitov sorry for being confused, I just edit my answer. Hope that it will be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to your table view cells with text fields.

Comment: Check that you return YES in textFieldShouldBeginEditing when you focusing next textfield.

Comment: I checked. It returns YES but nothing happened after first tap.

Comment: Strange because if this method is called after the first tap - then text field starts editing. Maybe someone ends editing just after start when the first tap is performed?

Comment: I have noticed just now that shouldEndEditing of first textField called after shouldBeginEditing of second textField. Can it be changed manually?

Comment: I don't think so. If you call endEditing on the specific cell instead of whole table view in your cell's delegate it should work.

Comment: I called delegate methods in cell's class. Now i call them in class contains tableView and it works. Please describe this one more time in single answer and i will mark it as correct answer.